# Una consulta con doble condición para que muestre 1 solo registro

Tags: sql-server

```
alter procedure usp_ConsultarNotasAlumnoExacto
@vcodeval char(3),
@vcodcur char(3)
as
select A.COD_ALU,ALUMNO,A.PRAC1_NOT,A.PRAC2_NOT,A.PRAC3_NOT,A.EXAM_P_NOT,A.EXAM_F_NOT,A.NOTA_TAR_PROMEDIO,PROMEDIO_TOTAL_CURSO,ESTADO,A.NOM_CUR
from VW_VistaNotas_Alumno A  inner join tb_nota B ON A.cod_alu = B.Cod_Alu
                            inner join tb_curso C ON B.cod_cur = C.Cod_cur
where (B.COD_ALU=@vcodeval and b.cod_cur=@vcodcur) 
go

EXEC usp_ConsultarNotasAlumnoExacto '102','110'
go
```

[image: Como me sale]

Quisiera que en ves de que me salga los 5 cursos , me saliera sólo 1 con la segunda condición

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres.. a qué te refieres con que te salga uno sólo con la segunda condición?

Comment: claro osea q cuando consulte la nota del alumno, pero que solo sea de su curso y no de los otros cursos , osea si es un profe del curso de ciencia que salga todas las notas del alumno pero solo del curso de ciencia

Comment: y porque no agregas en el where el curso? o la pareja profesor curso? asi como esta, es poco claro donde esta cada cosa y donde tenes el problema.

Comment: No sé si entiendo del todo lo que quieres, pero no bastaría con enviar el nombre del curso como parámetro?

Comment: gracias si con el nombre del curso como parametro en ves del codigo del curso si salia , gracias XD